# Code for overlaying image on image and text on images in JES

Tags: python

I need assistance in making a code that will overlay image on image and text on images in JES.

I am unable to start due to limited knowledge of Overlaying images on images, text on images, scaling text and image up or down and transparency levels.

If anyone will assist me it would be nice. Thanks

```
def scale(picture,factor):
  newHeight = int(factor*getHeight(picture))+1
  newWidth = int(factor*getWidth(picture))+1
  returnPic = makeEmptyPicture(int(newWidth),int(newHeight))
  sx = 0
  for tx in range(0,newWidth):
    sy = 0
    for ty in range(0,newHeight):
      if (int(sx) < getWidth(picture)) and (int(sy) < getHeight(picture)):
        sp = getPixel(picture,int(sx),int(sy))
        tp = getPixel(returnPic,tx,ty)
        setColor(tp,getColor(sp))
      sy = sy + (1/factor)
    sx = sx + (1/factor)

  show(returnPic)

def grayScaleNew():
   picture = makePicture("forbidden-city.jpg")
   for px in getPixels(picture):
     newRed = getRed(px) * 0.2121 
     newGreen = getGreen(px) * 0.7152
     newBlue = getBlue(px) *  0.0722
     luminance = newRed + newGreen + newBlue
     setColor(px,makeColor(luminance,luminance,luminance))

def testTransparentOverlay():

   # This function reads in two pictures and produces a new picture that
   # is made by copying picture 1 and then overlaying picture 2 on top
   # of picture 1. (It is placed in the centre of the image)
   # This requires the width and height of picture 2 to be less than 
   # the width and height of picture 2 (so it fits). So it checks 
   # that the size of each image is correct before creating the new picture.

   # 1. Get the two pictures and show them  
   file = pickAFile()
   picture1 = makePicture(file)
   file = pickAFile()
   picture2 = makePicture(file)
   show(picture1)
   show(picture2)

   #2. Test the size of the pictures - picture 2 needs to fit inside
   #   picture 1 (so check width and height)

   if getWidth(picture2) > getWidth(picture1):
      errorMessageWidth = "ERROR: The width of picture2 is greater than picture1"
      print(errorMessageWidth)
   elif getHeight(picture2) > getHeight(picture1):
      errorMessageWidth = "ERROR: The width of picture2 is greater than picture1"
      print(errorMessageWidth)
   else: #do the overlay and show the result
      #work out the position for overlaying first
      xMargin = (getWidth(picture1) - getWidth(picture2)) / 2
      yMargin = (getHeight(picture1) - getHeight(picture2)) / 2
      proportion = 60 #try 60% transparency
      picture3 = transparency(picture1, picture2, xMargin, yMargin, proportion)
      show(picture3)


def transparency(picture1, picture2, xStart, yStart, proportion):
     # overlays picture 2 in the centre of picture 1 with 
     # a transparency of proportion (%)
     # returns a new picture - copy of picture 1 with the overlay 
     # (there are no side effects)

     picture3 = duplicatePicture(picture1)

     # calculate the proportions of overlay and the base image
     # keep any decimal places until after calculations
     overlay = (proportion) / 100.0   # convert overlay from percentage to a fraction 
                                      # eg. 60% is 60/100 which is 0.6 
     base = (100-proportion) / 100.0  # convert base amount from percentage to a fraction 
                                      # eg. if overlap is 60% is (100-60) / 100 which is 0.5  

     #Copy all the pixels from picture 2 onto the new picture 3
     for x in range(0, getWidth(picture2)):
        for y in range(0, getHeight(picture2)):  
           pixel2 = getPixel(picture2, x, y)                # pixel to copy (and colours)
           pixel2Red   = getRed(pixel2)
           pixel2Green = getGreen(pixel2)
           pixel2Blue  = getBlue(pixel2) 

           pixel3 = getPixel(picture3, x+xStart, y+yStart)  # overlap pixel (and colours)
           pixel3Red   = getRed(pixel3)
           pixel3Green = getGreen(pixel3)
           pixel3Blue  = getBlue(pixel3)

           #combine the colours in correct proportions - convert back to integers
           newRed =   int(pixel2Red * overlay)   + int(pixel3Red * base)
           newGreen = int(pixel2Green * overlay) + int(pixel3Green* base)
           newBlue =  int(pixel2Blue * overlay)  + int(pixel3Blue * base)

           #set the new colours for picture3
           setRed(pixel3, newRed)
           setGreen(pixel3, newGreen)
           setBlue(pixel3, newBlue)


     return picture3
```

These are all the code I have written but I am unsure how to put them together to make it work as a whole. If that made any sense.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you need assistance with? Have you written any code at all?

Comment: Yes I have, I have written code for Grayscale, blending the image to centre, transparency strength and scaling image but I tried putting them all together but it doesn't seem to finish the task....it stops short...like I am able to overlay image in centre and grey scale the image but that seems to be it, it won't scale the image up or down and transparency level doesn't go up or down.

Comment: We can't help unless you provide a [mcve].

Comment: okay I have provided all the code that I have written, I am just unsure how to put them together and make it work as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Ill start by giving you a quote from the INFT1004 assignment you are asking for help with.

"**In particular, you should try not to use code or algorithms from external sources, and not to obtain help from people other than your instructors, as this can prevent you from mastering these concepts**"

It specifically says in this assignment that you should not ask people online or use code you find or request online, and is a breach of the University of Newcastle academic integrity code - you know the thing you did a module on before you started the course.
A copy of this post will be sent along to the course instructor.

Comment: oh I see but obviously I didn't get any answers from the questions I asked